# Write a txt file to host computer and not to the pi pico's root dir

Tags: directory, path

I have a pi pico set up as a data logger. It writes a txt file recording the data every 1s. When the program stops running, the text file is written to the pico's root dir. I want to set the file path to C:\Users\data.txt

My code is as follows:

```
# Open File
batch = input ("Enter Batch no. ")
date = input ("Enter the Date ")

batch1 = str(batch)
date1 = str(date)

file_path = 'C:/Users/alans/batch.txt'
file_mode = 'w'

with open(file_path, file_mode) as file:
  #  f.write("writefiledata")



def writefiledata(batch1,t, x):
    time = str(t)
    value = str(round(x, 2))
    file.write(date1 + "," + batch1 + "," + time + "," + value)
    file.write("\n")
    file.flush()
```

And I get the following error msg

> > > %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 37
> > > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone help